# Extract String value from BsonString

Tags: mongodb, scala

This code selects all elements from a mongodb collection :

```
import scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq
import org.mongodb.scala._
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Aggregates._
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Filters._
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Projections._
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Sorts._
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Updates._
import org.mongodb.scala.model._
import org.mongodb.scala.bson._

object Main extends App {

//http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.0/scaladoc/index.html#org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document
// Use a Connection String
val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://mymongo.com:27017")

 // get handle to "mydb" database
val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb")

// get a handle to the "test" collection
val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("mycol")

val observable: FindObservable[Document] = collection.find();
observable.subscribe ( new Observer[Document] {
  override def onNext(result: Document): Unit = 
  {
    println(result("question")+"->"+result("answer"))
  }
  override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println("Failed" + e.getMessage)
  override def onComplete(): Unit = println("Completed")
})


Thread.sleep(5000)

}
```

The output of this code is :

```
BsonString{value='map1'}->BsonString{value='value1'}
BsonString{value='map2'}->BsonString{value='value2'}
BsonString{value='map3'}->BsonString{value='value3'}
```

I'm expecting  :

```
map1->value1
map2->value2
map3->value3
```

I'm using Thread.sleep(5000) as observable.subscribe is non blocking and I need
to keep main thread alive to prevent main thread exiting before the observable.subscribe
completes.

Reading the api for BsonString http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/org/bson/BsonString.html
there does not appear to be a method to access value ?

Comment: how about [getValue()](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/org/bson/BsonString.html#getValue--)?

Comment: @Archeg please see my posted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing

```
println(result("question")+"->"+result("answer"))
```

with

```
println(result("question").asString.getValue+"->"+result("answer").asString.getValue)
```

prints expected result.

The result of `result("question")` is `BsonValue` , not `BsonString`.

The method `getValue` is documented at http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/?org/bson/BsonValue.html